# Make jQuery datatables keep the row number assigned when searching/sorting

Tags: jquery, datatables

I've got the following code to create a row number in jQuery Datatables:

```
"fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull){ 
        var index = iDisplayIndexFull + 1; 
        $('td:eq(0)', nRow).html(index); 
        return nRow;
     },
```

However, when I search for a certain value, the row numbers update. This is expected. My question is, is there anyway to make the row numbers remain the same after they are initially created?

Example:

```
 Initial output
 1     Team1
 2     Team2
 3     Team3
 4     Team4
 5     Team5

 After Searching
 2     Team2
 5     Team5
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
"fnDrawCallback": function ( oSettings ) {
 /* Need to redo the counters if filtered or sorted */
 if ( oSettings.bSorted || oSettings.bFiltered )
 {
 for ( var i=0, iLen=oSettings.aiDisplay.length ; i<iLen ; i++ )
 {
 $('td:eq(0)', oSettings.aoData[ oSettings.aiDisplay[i] ].nTr ).html( i+1 );
 }
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd set a `data` attribute on the rows initially like so:

```
"fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull){ 
        var index = iDisplayIndexFull + 1; 
        $('td:eq(0)', nRow).attr('data-index',$('td:eq(0)', nRow).attr('data-index')||index);
        $('td:eq(0)', nRow).html($('td:eq(0)', nRow).attr('data-index',index));
        return nRow;
     },
```

Comment: There seem to be a lot of errors in what you propose and since I don't really know what it's trying to accomplish, I'm not sure how to fix it. Help?

Answer (score 0):

You could store the original id in `aData`:

```
aData.index = iDisplayIndexFull + 1;
```

And then, you could access it later on with:

```
var index = oTable.fnGetData(your_row).index;
```

Comment: This may work, but my jQuery knowledge isn't enough to implement this. Could you help me out on how to use the data once it's stored?