# Index number on search should keep its original value, not restart

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

I am using datatables v1.10 which has improved a lot over time. However i am trying to add an index number.

So far i have managed to add the index number but i can't make a record keep it's original index number after search.

Let's say i have this table:

```
POSITION NAME
0        Tennis
1        Football
2        Basketball
```

if i would search on Basketball i should get POSITION 2 back like this:

```
POSITION NAME
2        Basketball
```

But rather than giving position 2, datatables start counting all over again at 0 (or 1 in my case because i made it start at 1)

I would like the index number to retain its correct value after search.

Last time i used:

```js
"fnDrawCallback": function ( oSettings ) {
     if ( oSettings.bSorted || oSettings.bFiltered ) {
        for ( var i=0, iLen=oSettings.aiDisplay.length ; i<iLen ; i++ ){
            $('td:eq(0)', oSettings.aoData[ oSettings.aiDisplay[i] ].nTr ).html( i+1 );
        }   
     }
},
```

I tried to convert this to their new api but i can not find a correct workaround.

This is the current server-side code i am using:

```php
require('ssp.class.php');

$result=SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns );
$start=$_REQUEST['start'] + 1;
foreach($result['data'] as &$res){
    $res["id"]=(string)$start;
    $start++;
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

and client-side:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var t = $('#table-data').DataTable( {               
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "index.php",
            "type": "GET"
        },
        "columns": [
            {"data": "position"},
            {"data": "name"},
        ]

    });
});
```

My issue is similar to: [Make jQuery datatables keep the row number assigned when searching/sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117145/make-jquery-datatables-keep-the-row-number-assigned-when-searching-sorting)

I tried the code suggested there but it doesn't seem to work in datatables v1.10 (i changed the correct api namings)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can be achieved by following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var t = $('#table-data').DataTable( {               
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "index.php",
        "type": "GET"
    },
    "columns": [
        {"data": "position"},
        {"data": "name"},
    ]

});
t.on( 'order.dt search.dt', function () {
    t.column(0, { order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
        cell.innerHTML = i+1;
    } );
} ).draw(); 
});
```